# What is wrong in sort function, need improvements also

Tags: javascript, performance, logic

I hava a json object have some records, and I need to sort the object,

code:

```
var data = [
{
  "MRData": {        
    "StandingsTable": {
      "StandingsLists": [
        {
          "season": "2014",
          "round": "5",
          "DriverStandings": [
            {
              "position": "2",
              "positionText": "1",
              "points": "100",
              "wins": "4",
              "Driver": {...},
              "Constructors": [...]
            },
            {
              "position": "1",
              "positionText": "2",
              "points": "97",
              "wins": "1",
              "Driver": {...},
              "Constructors": [...]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
];
```

//What is Wrong in This function

```
function sortObj(obj, nextObj){
    console.log(obj.position);
    console.log(nextObj.position);
    if(obj.position < nextObj.position){
        return obj;
    }else{
        return nextObj;
    }
}

var driverObjects = data[0].MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
console.log(driverObjects);
var sortedData = driverObjects.sort(sortObj); //Do I need to use any other functions //like filter, map ?
console.log(sortedData);
```

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzfrK/)

Have a look at the console, to use the output, I was excepting the output like

[Object { position="1", positionText="1", points="100", more...}, Object { position="2", positionText="2", points="97", more...}]

But it is displaying same as passed function.

1. please correct the function mistakes.
2. Give me an optimized or more standard code implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function for the sort method should return `-1` (when the second parameter is greater), `0` (when both parameters are equal) or `1` (when the first parameter is greater)

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

so you need this sort function:

```
function sortObj(obj, nextObj){
    return obj.position - nextObj.position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it before but may be do not check properly, Thanks a lot, such a silly mistake I did

Answer (score 1):

sortObj() should return either *positive* value or *negative* value or *0*

You can do like this..

```
function sortObj(obj, nextObj){
    console.log(obj.position);
    console.log(nextObj.position);
    return nextObj.position-obj.position
}
```